# How can I create a new variable which calculates sum of a specific variable (by ID) containing multiple observation in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, sum, new-operator, proc

For example, I want to create a new dataset (Data2) from Data1.

A new variable, cost in data2 is calculated as sum of multiple observation by ID in material of data1.

(Data1)

```
ID  material
1   4
1   4
1   4
2   2
2   4
2   4
3   2
3   6
3   6
4   5
4   5
4   5
4   5
5   2
5   4
5   4
5   8
```

(Data2)

```
ID  cost    
1   12  #4+4+4
2   10  #2+4+4
3   14  #2+6+6
4   20  #5+5+5+5
5   18  #2+4+4+8
```

I have used SAS EG version only for simple analysis, and recently I started to use proc sql procedure. As a beginner in SAS coding (proc sql), it was very hard to approach the answer, for myself. Thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `PROC SQL`, this is a straight forward use of `GROUP BY`

```
proc sql;
  select id, sum(material) as sum from mydataset group by id;
  quit;
```

You could manually compute this in a datastep also if you don't want to use `PROC SQL`

```
proc sort data=mydataset;
  by id;
run;

data sums;
  set mydataset;
  by id;

  if first.id then sum = 0;
  sum + material;
  if last.id then output;

  keep id sum;

run;

proc print data=sums;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!

Accroding to your advice, I will try to perform the analysis as follows, later in my office.

proc sql;
  create Data2 as
  select ID, sum(material) as sum 
  from Data1 
  group by ID;
  quit;

Answer (score 1):

Base SAS has several procedures that will present aggregated values over a group. `MEANS`, `SUMMARY`, and reporting procedures such as `REPORT` and `TABULATE`.  The procedures can also save output data sets containing the computed aggregates.

```
data have; input
ID  material_cost;datalines;
1   4
1   4
1   4
2   2
2   4
2   4
3   2
3   6
3   6
4   5
4   5
4   5
4   5
5   2
5   4
5   4
5   8
run;

title "Proc MEANS";
proc means data=have sum noNobs maxdec=0;
  class id;
  var material_cost;
run;

title "Proc SUMMARY";
proc summary data=have print sum noNobs maxdec=0;
  class id;
  var material_cost;
run;

title "Proc REPORT";
proc report data=have;
  columns id material_cost;
  define id / group;
run;

title "Proc TABULATE";
proc tabulate data=have;
  class id;
  var material_cost;
  table id, material_cost*sum / NoCellMerge;
run;
```